# real-time message processing method body in seperate thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have method which is passed in real-time data constantly.

The method then evaluates the data:

```
void processMessage(String messageBeingPassed) {
  //evaluate the message here and do something with it
  //depending on the current state of the message
  //if message.equals("test") 
  //call separate thread to save to database etc...
  //etc...
}
```

My question is, is there any advantage to putting the **entire** method body inside a thread for better performance?

such as:

```
void processMessage(String messageBeingPassed) {
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
  //evaluate the message here and do something
  //depending on the current state of the message
  //if message.equals("test") 
  //call separate thread to save to database etc...
  //etc...
  }
  //start main body thread for this current message etc...
 } 
}
```

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Don't ask. Measure. *You* are the only one with access to the code and the data. Spin it up, and *profile* it. Then you'll *know* instead of relying on *guesses* from people on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on various factors. If that method is a bottleneck for your application (i.e. you get long queues of messages waiting to be processed), then it will likely improve your performance up to a certain point, and then degrade again if you use too many threads. So you should use a thread pool and have like 4 threads responsible for that, or some other amount that works best.

However, if you don't get such queues of messages, then that's hardly going to help you.

Either way, **the only** way to know for sure is through testing and profiling of what performs best in **your** application.

Comment: Thanks. Though I will do some tests that pretty much confirms what I thought which is its not really needed (for my specific case) for any significant performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage is that you can process multiple messages at once, and the calling method won't need to block while the message is being processed (in other words, message processing will be asynchronous instead of synchronous).  The disadvantage is that you open yourself up to data races / deadlocks / etc if you're not careful about designing your methods - generally, if your runnable will ONLY be operating on the `messageBeingPassed` object (and not e.g. on any static fields), then you should be fine.  In addition, threads carry some overhead with them, which you can reduce by using an `ExecutorService` instead of constructing your own thread objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on the rate of data and the time taken by the "processMessage". If the next data arrives before the  "processMessage" method finishes its execution of the previous data, it is a good idea to use a thread inside the "processMessage" method

Comment: for the processMessage method there is only a few conditional checks, and once a condition is met it locks it in a specific state so that subsequent checks are reduced significantly. But I will definitely be testing to see if I can get any more performance out from it.